# Is this namespace issue

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, namespaces, face-detection

This is my code, I got from this [link](http://www.cognotics.com/opencv/servo_2007_series/part_2/)

```
    int main(int agrc, char **argv)
    {
           HaarClassifierCascade *p = 0;
           MemStorage *pstore = 0;
           Seq *Faceseq;
           int i;

           Mat test_sample = imread("1.jpg");
           pstore = CreateMemStorage(0);
           p = (HaarClassifierCascade *)Load(("/home/itachi/opencv-2.4.6/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"),0,0,0);
          if( !test_sample || !pstore || !p)
          {
                printf("Initialization failed : %s \n",(!test_sample)? "didn't load image file" : (!p)? "didn't load Haar cascade --" "make sure path is correct" : "failed to allocate memory for data storage");
                exit(-1);
          }

          Faceseq = HaarDetectObjects(test_sample,p,pstore,1.1,3,CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,Size(0,0));
          NamedWindow("Haar Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

          for(i=0;i<(Faceseq? Faceseq->total:0);i++)
          {
               Rect *r = (Rect*)GetSeqElem(Faceseq,i);
               Point pt1 = { r->x, r->y };
               Point pt2 = { r->x + r->width, r->y + r->height };
               Rectangle(test_sample,pt1,pt2,CV_RGB(0,255,0),3,4,0);
          }
          ShowImage("Haar Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
          WaitKey(0);
          DestroyWindow("Haar Window");

          ReleaseImage(test_sample);
          if(p) ReleaseHaarClassifierCascade(&p);
          if(pstore) ReleaseMemStorage (&pstore);
    }
```

I am trying this code in my new system, where I installed opencv recently. Previously, when using from my old system, I normally used functions like **ShowImage** without a **cv** tag before it. but compiling this code is giving me the following error :

```
    facedetecthaar.cpp:28:91: error: ‘HaarDetectObjects’ was not declared in this scope
    facedetecthaar.cpp:29:47: error: ‘NamedWindow’ was not declared in this scope
```

And many more similar to this. If I add **Cv** infront of these functions, it becomes fine. Any reason why this is required? Is this a problem of namespace not working? Please help me here. This is my Makefile:

```
    LIBS=`pkg-config --libs opencv`
    INCLUDE=`pkg-config --cflags opencv`



    Facedetect: facedetecthaar.o
            g++ $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)

    facedetecthaar.o: facedetecthaar.cpp
            g++ -c $^ $(INCLUDE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead of showImage
This is easy

```
// Open the window
cv::namedWindow("foo");

// Display the image m in this window
cv::imshow("foo", m);
```

And the cvxxxx_xxx before the functions are part of the function names, you should not remove them.

All of this functionality which start with cv are old and there are replacements for all of them in new version of openCV which for some case are even faster.

you can see the complete diffrences here:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/index.html openCV 2.0

http://docs.opencv.org/index.html openCV 2.4

Comment: Thanks for help. Could you please look at the link I provided? The code has functions starting with Cvxxx_xxx. I want to know if this is due to namespace of if the function name itself has to begin with Cv? Thanks.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan `CvxXxxxx` applies to functions and types of the C interface to OpenCV. The C++ stuff all lives inside the `cv` namespace.

Comment: @Khashayar Is there anyway I could find the new equivalent of the old functions?

Comment: all the old ones are with IplImages so I think the easiest way is to search the same function for Mat and find the right one.

Comment: @Khashayar for eg : CvHaarClassifierCascade, as you have mentioned earlier, has to come from the old library. How can I get the new one? I did not understand you clear enough. my Apologies.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#cascadeclassifier-detectmultiscale for eg: this is instead of cvHaarDetectObjects

Comment: found it with normal search of "haardetectobjects opencv" :D